# Во время выполнения программного клика по кнопке (doClick), не отображаются остальные кнопки

Tags: java, swing

Совсем новичок в Swing, возможно не до конца понимаю потоки или еще что-то
В общем, такая проблема -- класс Field представляет собой окно, содержащее панель из кнопок 4 на 4 (field).

[image: Класс Field]

Класс AI -- его наследник, но также в конструкторе программно вызываются нажатия по кнопкам на главной диагонали. Дело в том, что когда это нажатие осуществляется, само поле из кнопок не отображается. Примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходник программы:

класс Field

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Field extends JFrame {

    JPanel field;   //панель будет содержать кнопки 4x4
    JButton[][] buttons;    //собственно, кнопки

    public Field() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        field = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4));   //инициализируем панель
        field.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

        buttons = new JButton[4][4];
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
                field.add(buttons[i][j]);
            }

        add(field);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Класс AI:

```
public class AI extends Field {
    public AI() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            buttons[i][i].doClick();
        }
    }
}
```

Вызываю AI асинхронно (SwingUtilities.invokeLater)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите нажать программно(не пользователем) можете использовать такой вариант:

```
public AI() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                buttons[i][i].doClick();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

т.е. выполнять нажатие в параллельном потоке